# How to give names to items in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have created array of JFields;

```
JFields[] field = new JField[5];

for(int j = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    field[j] = new JField();
}
```

What I want to do is give each item in the array a name, so for example, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.

I tried accomplishing that like this;

```
String[] field = {field1, field2, field3, field4, field5}
```

also tried doing it like this;

```
field[j] = {field1, field2, field3, field4, field5}
```

but neither work. Could someone tell me how I can do it, thanks.

Also, how can I call individual items from that array

I tried for example `field[0] OR field[1]` etc. but that doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You don't mean `JTextField field1 = field[0]; JTextField field2 = field[1];...`?

Comment: your `for` loop has a typo (i->j)

Comment: "I tried for example field[0] OR field[1] etc. but that doesn't work." Please elaborate on this. I don't understand what you tried, and what you didn't manage to obtain.

Comment: @user3325350 Don't forget to accept an answer (click the checkmark) if the answer meets your needs. It lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 points for accepting an answer, and it awards 15 points to the person that provided the answer.

Answer (score 4):

That's what your array is for. Because you have a JTextField array called fields, you've already got "names" for items in the array such as, field[2] and field[3], so there's no need to give variables "names" here.

You state:

> I tried for example field[0] OR field[1] etc. but that doesn't work.

Then you're doing something wrong, but not showing us what. Please expand on what you mean by "doesn't work", including showing us how you try to use `field[0]` or `field[1]` and what errors or exceptions you might get, and we'll be able to give you a much more complete answer.

I'm guessing that you've got a scoping problem, that perhaps your array is declared in a  method or constructor block, or some other loop or control structure block making it not visible where you're trying to use it, but I can't tell for sure. More code will help us tell you more on this.

---

**Edit**
For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextFieldFun extends JPanel {
   public static final int TEXT_FIELD_COUNT = 8;
   private static final int COLS = 10;

   // array of JTextFields
   private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[TEXT_FIELD_COUNT];

   // JTextField used to enter text to go into one of the array item fields
   private JTextField enterField = new JTextField(COLS);

   // spinner to choose which fields item to have its text set
   private JSpinner fieldIndexSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, TEXT_FIELD_COUNT - 1, 1));

   public TextFieldFun() {
      // JPanel to hold the array of fields
      JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
         // create field items for array
         fields[i] = new JTextField(COLS);
         fields[i].setEditable(false);
         fields[i].setFocusable(false);
         JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel();
         rowPanel.add(new JLabel("Field " + i + ":"));
         rowPanel.add(fields[i]); // and put into a JPanel
         textFieldPanel.add(rowPanel);  // put JPanel into grid layout using JPanel
      }

      EnterAction enterAction = new EnterAction();
      enterField.setAction(enterAction);

      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
      bottomPanel.add(new JLabel("Row to Change:"));
      bottomPanel.add(fieldIndexSpinner);
      bottomPanel.add(new JLabel("Text:"));
      bottomPanel.add(enterField);
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(enterAction));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(textFieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   private class EnterAction extends AbstractAction {
      public EnterAction() {
         super("Enter");
      }
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // get the text from the enterField JTextField
         String text = enterField.getText();

         // get the int from the JSpinner
         int index = ((Integer)fieldIndexSpinner.getValue()).intValue();

         // set the JTextField in the array whose index matches that of the spinner value
         fields[index].setText(text);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TextFieldFun mainPanel = new TextFieldFun();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextFieldFun");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: That's a great insight.  Within the array, the "name" of the element is its index.

Comment: What I mean is that, I in that for loop i created above, I added a  this statement field[0].setText("Hi"), it does that fine. But when I change the [0] to say [1] or something else, it does add the text, instead it changes the size of the textfield. I am sorry for not explaining myself clearly. Thanks.

Comment: @user3325350: Please edit your question and show the specific code that you are using. Try to show the entire loop, try to show real code, not sort-of code (like your original question has -- ?JFields??), try to describe in even greater details your program's misbehavior, because what you're describing above, calling `someTextField.setText("foo")` changing the size of the field can't really happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you must refer to them by name as you insist, use a HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, JField> fieldNameMap = new HashMap<String, JField>();

fieldNameMap.put("field1", field[j]);
//repeat ad nauseum

//when you want to retrieve one
JField myField = fieldNameMap.get("field1");
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking doesn't really make sense, unless what you are trying to do is work with each individual Field instance independent of referencing it in the array.  The Map solution recommended above would work, as would just instantiating each Field independently and assigning it to a variable.

```
JField field1 = new JField();
JField field2 = new JField();
JField field3 = new JField();
JField field4 = new JField();
JField field5 = new JField();
JFields[] fields = { field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 };
// The following 2 statements reference the same JField instance.
System.out.println( field5.toString() );
System.out.println( fields[ 4 ].toString() );
```

The Map makes more sense to me, but the null check step is a pain in the butt (I guess you should also be null checking the array solution...i'll leave that up to the reader).

```
Map<String,JField> fields = new HashMap<String,JField>();
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    String key = "field" + ( i + 1 );
    JField value = new JField();
    fields.put( key, value );
}
JField field = fields.get( "field5" );
if ( field != null ) {
    System.out.println( field.toString() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are meant to be accessed using the indices (ie `fields[0], fields[1]`, etc).

If you really need your structure to be able to access your items by a name then you need to change your data structure from an array to a map. I recommend using a HashMap.

You can import your array into a HashMap like this:

```
HashMap<String,JField> map = new HashMap<String,JField>();
for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++ ){
    map.put("field"+i ,field[i]);
}
```

Now you can access your JFields by name:

```
map.get("field1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't give names explicitly to arrays. What you're looking for is a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). It allows for looking up values by keys. In your case, the key is the "name" and the value is the integer.